# Does a faster hard drive cause a laptop's battery to drain faster?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, speed, hardware-rec

I currently have a slow 5400 rpm drive in my laptop and I am looking at installing a 7200rpm drive.

The new drive is reported to be 100 times faster than the old drive. The traditional advice would say that a 7200rpm drive, drain laptop batteries faster, however if you compare the specifications this appears not to be the case is this correct? For example:

**My current 5400rpm drive:**

- spin up power: 4.5w
- seek power: 2.2w
- read/write: 1.9w

**Replacement 7200rpm drive:**

- seek power: 2.3w
- read/write: 2.1w
- spin up power: 5.5w

If I read this correctly, does this mean switching to a 7200rpm drive will have a negligible power drain impact? For those interested, I am comparing the following two drives:

- [5400 RPM Toshiba MK2553GSX](http://www.sdd.toshiba.com/main.aspx?Path=StorageSolutions/2.5-inchHardDiskDrives/MK2553GSX/MK2553GSXSpecifications)
- [7200 RPM MKxx61GSY Series](http://www.sdd.toshiba.com/techdocs/MKxx61GSY.pdf)

Comment: Note regarding which stackexchange site is best, this site seems to have hardware related stuff, ie http://serverfault.com/questions/13839/does-orientation-affect-hard-drive-lifespan

Comment: Hardly 100 times faster, possibly 50% faster on a good day but probably closer to 25% on average. Superuser.com is where this belongs BTW.

Comment: @Jacob - SF is "...for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity." (from the FAQ). Questions like yours are typically better handled over on SU. It'll get migrated there shortly, no need to re-post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that those 'small' differences will have a significant impact on battery life.  It's not going to halve it but it will be noticable.

Comment: Anecdotally, I can say that when I moved from a 5400 RPM drive to a 7200 RPM drive in my old laptop, I did not notice any change in battery life, while I did notice an increase in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Better materials will reduce the friction in the spindle once it has spun up, leading to lowered power use while spinning. Do note the difference in the spin-up power of the drives though; the drive that spins faster needs more power to get spun up.

Answer (score 0):

7200rpm drives use slightly more power but usually not enough to be noticeable. The optimal solution is an SSD drive if you don't need a huge amount of storage space, ie: less than 500gb.

Answer (score -1):

It's actually the opposite.
After replacing my laptop HDD with SDD my laptop works faster and the battery lasts longer.
So no HDD. Use only SSD.

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked.  Rather it  is a suggestion, which is a comment.